# Jquery Slider working in Fiddle but not in Browser, Gives Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I am working on jquery slider, and implemented in JsFiddle successfully but not working in Browser and showing error like this :

```
  file:///C:/Users/kumarah/Dropbox/Scheduler/FreshStart/VERSION_3.5/skillselection/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
  file:///C:/Users/kumarah/Dropbox/Scheduler/FreshStart/VERSION_3.5/skillselection/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
  file:///C:/Users/kumarah/Dropbox/Scheduler/FreshStart/VERSION_3.5/skillselection/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
  file:///C:/Users/kumarah/Dropbox/Scheduler/FreshStart/VERSION_3.5/skillselection/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///C:/Users/kumarah/Dropbox/Scheduler/FreshStart/VERSION_3.5/skillselection/images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///C:/Users/kumarah/Dropbox/Scheduler/FreshStart/VERSION_3.5/skillselection/images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I tried looking for this on StackOverflow and found lots of answers, but could not find success. Even tried copying all the missing images in the images folder but still it shows missing.

Here is the working fiddle for the same

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hawkeye15/qng5935v/15/)

But not working in Browser, whose code is

**.js**

```
 <script>
         $(function() {
// setup master volume
$( "#master1" ).slider({
  value: 50,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  animate: true
});
// setup graphic EQ
$( "#eq1 > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  });
});
 });

 $(function() {
// setup master volume
$( "#master2" ).slider({
  value: 30,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  animate: true
});
// setup graphic EQ
$( "#eq2 > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  });
});
 });

 $(function() {
// setup master volume
$( "#master3" ).slider({
  value: 20,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  animate: true
});
// setup graphic EQ
$( "#eq3 > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 20 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  });
});
});
$(function() {
// setup master volume
$( "#master4" ).slider({
  value: 90,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  animate: true
});
// setup graphic EQ
$( "#eq4 > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  });
});
});
```

**index.html**

```
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Slider - Multiple sliders</title>

            <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
        <!--  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> -->

           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/7.1.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css" >
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/7.1.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">


        </head>
        <body style="margin:10px;padding:10px">



        <div class = "row">
             <div class = "col-md-12">

            <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px; text-align:center;">
              <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
              <b>OVERALL</b>
            </p>

            <div id="master4" align="center" style=" margin:50px 50px 50px 0; color:#ffffff;"></div>

             </div>

             </div>


             <div class = "row">

             <div class = "col-md-4">
            <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px; text-align:center;">
              <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
              Analytical
            </p>

            <div id="master1" style="width:260px; margin:15px;"></div>

            <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="padding:4px;margin-top:4em; text-align:center;">
              <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-signal" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
              Sub Skills
            </p>

            <div id="eq1">
              <span>88</span>
              <span>77</span>
              <span>55</span>
              <span>33</span>
              <span>40</span>
              <span>45</span>

            </div>
            </div>

             <div class = "col-md-4">

            <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px; text-align:center;">
              <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
              Communication
            </p>

            <div id="master2" style="width:260px; margin:15px;"></div>

            <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="padding:4px;margin-top:4em; text-align:center;">
              <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-signal" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
              Sub Skills
            </p>

            <div id="eq2">

              <span>77</span>
              <span>55</span>

              <span>45</span>
              <span>70</span>
            </div>
             </div>

             <div class = "col-md-4">

            <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px; text-align:center;">
              <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
              Theory
            </p>

            <div id="master3" style="width:260px; margin:15px;"></div>

            <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="padding:4px;margin-top:4em; text-align:center;">
              <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-signal" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
              Sub-Skills
            </p>

            <div id="eq2">
              <span>33</span>
              <span>40</span>
              <span>45</span>
              <span>70</span>
            </div>
             </div>


             </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included bootstrap slider javascript and css in the page.
Include this css and script in page.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/7.1.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css" >





<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/7.1.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>



 <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>jQuery UI Slider - Multiple sliders</title>

            <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/7.1.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css" >
        </head>
        <body style="margin:10px;padding:10px">

        <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class = "row text-center">
          <div >
            <img src="logohead.jpg" style="float: center;width:250px;height:120px;">
          </div> 
         </div>
        </div>

         <div class = "row">
         <div class = "col-md-12">

        <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px; text-align:center;">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
          <b>OVERALL</b>
        </p>

        <div id="master4" align="center" style=" margin:50px 50px 50px 0; color:#ffffff;"></div>

         </div>

         </div>


         <div class = "row">

         <div class = "col-md-4">
        <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px; text-align:center;">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
          Analytical
        </p>

        <div id="master1" style="width:260px; margin:15px;"></div>

        <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="padding:4px;margin-top:4em; text-align:center;">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-signal" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
          Sub Skills
        </p>

        <div id="eq1">
          <span>88</span>
          <span>77</span>
          <span>55</span>
          <span>33</span>
          <span>40</span>
          <span>45</span>

        </div>
        </div>

         <div class = "col-md-4">

        <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px; text-align:center;">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
          Communication
        </p>

        <div id="master2" style="width:260px; margin:15px;"></div>

        <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="padding:4px;margin-top:4em; text-align:center;">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-signal" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
          Sub Skills
        </p>

        <div id="eq2">

          <span>77</span>
          <span>55</span>

          <span>45</span>
          <span>70</span>
        </div>
         </div>

         <div class = "col-md-4">

        <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px; text-align:center;">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-volume-on" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
          Theory
        </p>

        <div id="master3" style="width:260px; margin:15px;"></div>

        <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="padding:4px;margin-top:4em; text-align:center;">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-signal" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
          Sub-Skills
        </p>

        <div id="eq2">
          <span>33</span>
          <span>40</span>
          <span>45</span>
          <span>70</span>
        </div>
         </div>


         </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/7.1.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>



         <script>
$(function() {
// setup master volume
$( "#master1" ).slider({
  value: 50,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  animate: true
});
// setup graphic EQ
$( "#eq1 > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  });
});
});

$(function() {
// setup master volume
$( "#master2" ).slider({
  value: 30,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  animate: true
});
// setup graphic EQ
$( "#eq2 > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  });
});
});

$(function() {
// setup master volume
$( "#master3" ).slider({
  value: 20,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  animate: true
});
// setup graphic EQ
$( "#eq3 > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 20 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  });
});
});
$(function() {
// setup master volume
$( "#master4" ).slider({
  value: 90,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  animate: true
});
// setup graphic EQ
$( "#eq4 > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical"
  });
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error is still there but 5 in number